# Net Core - AutoMapper an entity with his parent

Tags: c#, automapper

I've tried to automap an entity with his parent but it's not working as I expected.

I have a company which can have some categories.

When I tried to get my category and his company inside, I have some fields I don't want to get (for example the siret, the connections or the passwords fields).

This is the result :

```
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Toot3",
        "products": [],
        "company": {
            "id": 1,
            "siret": "10000000000000",
            "name": "Tootland",
            "postal": 33000,
            "city": "Bordeaux",
            "country": "France",
            "address": null,
            "mail": "xxx",
            "status": "waiting",
            "created": "2020-07-08T18:51:52.051339",
            "lastConnection": "2020-07-13T20:41:05.1292985",
            "passwordHash": "xxx",
            "passwordSalt": "xxx",
            "categs": []
        },
        "companyId": 1
    }
```

My request to get all the categories and his parent :

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Categ>> GetAllWithProducts()
        {
            return await _context.Categ
            .Include(cm => cm.Products)
            .Include(cm => cm.Company)
            .ToListAsync();
        }
```

This is my company class :

```
public class Company
    {
        public const string STATUS_WAITING = "waiting";
        public const string STATUS_VALIDATED = "validated";
        public const string STATUS_REJECTED = "rejected";

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Siret { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Postal { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string Mail { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public DateTime Created { get; set; }
        public DateTime LastConnection { get; set; }
        public byte[] PasswordHash { get; set; }
        public byte[] PasswordSalt { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Categ> Categs { get; set; }
    }
```

Then my categ class :

```
public class CategMagazine
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
        public Company Company { get; set; }
        public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    }
```

An extract of my AutoMapperProfiles class :

```
    CreateMap<Company, CompanyForListDto>();
    CreateMap<Categ, CategForListDto>()
        .ForMember(dest => dest.Company,
        opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Company));
```

The CompanyForListDto

```
public class CompanyForListDto
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Postal { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
    }
```

The CategForListDto

```
public class CategForListDto
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public CompanyForListDto Company { get; set; }
    }
```

Thanks you in advance for your help.

Best regards.

(PS : Sorry for my bad english)

Comment: What version of automapper are you using? Please add `Company` and `CategMagazine` and hod do you invoke mapping. Also `it's not working` not very good description.

Comment: Thank you, I add some details. I was so in my code I forget to give some details and explain what I tried to do.